# Decision Tree Of SkLearn: Overfitting or Bug?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm analyzing the training error and validation error of my decision tree model using the tree package of sklearn.

```
#compute the rms error
def compute_error(x, y, model):
 yfit = model.predict(x.toarray())
 return np.mean(y != yfit) 

def drawLearningCurve(model,xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest):
 sizes = np.linspace(2, 25000, 50).astype(int)
 train_error = np.zeros(sizes.shape)
 crossval_error = np.zeros(sizes.shape)

 for i,size in enumerate(sizes):

  model = model.fit(xTrain[:size,:].toarray(),yTrain[:size])

  #compute the validation error
  crossval_error[i] = compute_error(xTest,yTest,model)

  #compute the training error
  train_error[i] = compute_error(xTrain[:size,:],yTrain[:size],model)

from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
drawLearningCurve(clf, xtr, ytr, xte, yte)
```

The problem is (I don't know whether it is a problem) that if I give a decision tree as model to the function `drawLearningCurve`,  I receive the result of the training error as `0.0` in each loop. Is it related to the nature of my dataset, or that of the tree package of sklearn? Or is there something else wrong?

PS: training error is absolutely not 0.0 at other models like naive-bayes, knn or ann.

Comment: It is completely possible to have a training error of 0.0 using a decision tree as a classifier, especially if there are no two observations with the same input variables and different output variable (the classification category). Obviously, in this case you are subject of a great amount of overfitting. Be aware, I am talking in general, as I do not know the nature of your dataset.

Comment: Since you're using sparse matrices, you probably have a lot of features, and with the default settings I wouldn't be surprised if decision trees on data with many features will overfit badly. That said, I'm voting to close, as it's impossible to tell for sure what's happening without seeing your data. You should try different settings (e.g. using `GridSearchCV`).

Comment: i tried it also with different settings but it still gives the same result. I believe there is something wrong but i dont know where it is. Anyway, i preffered to use other algorithms instead of decision tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commends give some pretty useful directions. I'd just like to add the parameter you might want to tweak is called `max_depth`.

What worries me more is your `compute_error` function is odd. The fact that you get an error of `0` says your classifier makes no errors on the training set. However, if it did make any mistakes your error function won't tell you that.

```
import numpy as np
np.mean([0,0,0,0] != [0,0,0,0]) # perfect match, error is 0
0.0

np.mean([0,0,0,0] != [1, 1, 1, 1]) # 100% wrong answers
1.0

np.mean([0,0,0,0] != [1, 1, 1, 0]) # 75% wrong answers
1.0

np.mean([0,0,0,0] != [1, 1, 0, 0]) # 50% wrong answers
1.0

np.mean([0,0,0,0] != [1, 1, 2, 2]) # 50% wrong answers
1.0
```

What you want is `np.sum(y != yfit)`, or even better, one of the error functions that come with sklearn, such as `accuracy_score`.